# Forcing sscanf to return more than number of arguments satisfied

Tags: c++, c, scanf, format-specifiers

My software validation group is testing a piece of code like the following:

```
unsigned int alarm_id;  
char         alarm_text[16];  
static const char text_string[] = "105, Water_Boiling";  
signed int   arguments_satisfied =  
    sscanf(text_string,  
           "%3d, %16s",
           &alarm_id, &alarm_text[0]);
if (arguments_satisfied < 2)
{
   system_failure();
}
```

Using the code fragment above, is there a way to get `sscanf` to return a value greater than 2 without changing the format specifier or changing the arguments to `sscanf`?

They are exercising the `if` statement expression, using a unit testing tool.

For C++, are there any differences with the above fragment when compiling as C++?
(We plan to use the same code, but compile as C++.)

FYI, we are using an ARM7 processor with IAR Embedded Workbench.

Comment: Are you trying to make it return greater than 2, or are you trying to ensure that your if statement will never miss a failure?  But, no difference for c++.

Comment: If the alarm_text field of the `text_string` is ever 16 or more characters long, the `%16s` format will write a `'\0'` just past the end of the `alarm_text` array. The `alarm_text` array needs to have 17 elements or format specifier needs to be `%15s`.

Comment: In the `system_failure` function, does the world blow up?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey:  Essentially, yes, the system's world blows up (sent to a safe holding pattern).

Comment: Might a compiler optimize all the code up to the `if()` and realize `arguments_satisfied` _must_ be 2 and then optimize out `system_failure()`?

Comment: My preferred test condition would be `if (arguments_satisfied != 2)`. The only correct, expected return value is 2; anything else warrants error handling.  Occasionally you may be interested in how many integers there were in a string, and you might then accept different numbers as 'correct enough'.  But for the normal uses, the `!= expected` condition covers EOF (usually -1), no valid data (0), and less valid data than expected (1 in this example). It also covers erroneous behaviour like a return value of 3.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler:  The issue is that with your expression, there are still 3 paths:  less than 2, equal to 2 and greater than 2.  Which still leaves the issue of making `sscanf` return greater than 2 in order to test the greater than 2 path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sscanf returns the number of arguments converted. It cannot convert more arguments than you have told it about. Therefore, unless the format string is changed, sscanf cannot return a value greater than 2. One possible exception -- it may be possible for EOF to be returned if you run out of data before the first argument is converted, but I suspect that only applies to scanf, not sscanf.

Comment: And since EOF is guaranteed to be negative (even though it is not guaranteed to be -1), that will still not return a value greater than 2.

Answer (score 1):

For many toolchains (and I'm pretty sure IAR is one), if you have a symbol in an object file and a library, the linker will link to the one in an object file in preference to the one in the library.

So you may be able to provide your own `sscanf()` function to link during tests and have it return whatever you like.

If the linker has a problem with a symbol conflict between your `sscanf()` implementation and one in the library, and alternative that may work is to have you unit test `sscanf()` use a different name (such as `unittest_sscanf`) and have the build system define a macro to rename `sscanf()` during the build using something like `/Dsscanf=unittest_sscanf` for the module under test.

Of course, it may be tricky to make sure that other `sscanf()` calls that aren't under test don't cause problems.